# Help in understanding project euler's question #54

Tags: c#

I'm trying to solve project euler [problem #54](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=54) in C#, but I'm confused to understand what to they mean with **5H 5C 6S 7S KD**? Could anyone please help in understanding this part?

Comment: if you can't work that out, I suspect the rest of the question might be beyond you (either that or you hit submit a bit too quickly)...and I'm not being insulting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is about playing cards; 5-of-hearts, 5-of-clubs, 6-of-spades, 7-of-spades, king-of-diamonds; i.e. 5♥ 5♣ 6♠ 7♠ K♦

Answer (score 1):

It just describes a hand of the following cards:

- 5 of hearts
- 5 of clubs
- 6 of spades
- 7 of spades
- King of diamonds